# Receive dynamic query from endpoint and parse to BsonDocument/Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to achieve the following:
Let's say I have a GET endpoint where I can send MongoDB query-like filters, something similar to:

```
http://localhost:8080/entities?filter={ _id: { $eq: "65ec2f531142aac1738c2203" } }
```

I want to make this dynamic query with MongoDB where I can receive any kind of query, parse it properly to a .NET format and use with for querying, but I can't find any docs that help me out with that.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank y'all!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`BsonDocument.Parse`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_Parse.htm) to parse the query and the submit it using [`IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>.FindAsync`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync.htm).
But keep in mind that this opens a wide range of options to the user while providing you only a few tools to apply limits. As a minimum, you should limit the number of rows that is returned by the query.

IMHO, creating an OData endpoint is a better option. This also supports sorting and paging. To do so, follow a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio) on how to create an OData endpoint with ASP.NET Core and return [`IMongoCollection<YourType>.AsQueryable`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_AsQueryable__1.htm) in a query action.